# Do we have publicly available Postman collections?

Tags: postman

I read that for http api's, we can have swagger json document or postman collection. And these files can be imported into rest united, so that restunited will automatically generate client SDK.

I wanted to know if there are any postman collections, publicly available, so that I can test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some postman collections published to Github:

https://github.com/heremaps/postman-collections

Comment: I could find some more.. following your tip from github.. https://github.com/PlayFab/PostmanCollection